# Optimize Application of Python Gensim Search Functions

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has a text column. I am splitting the DataFrame into two parts based on the value in another column. One of those parts is indexed into a gensim similarity model. The other part is then fed into the model to find the indexed text that is most similar. This involves a search function to enumerate over each item in the indexed part.

The goal is to compare each row in df_yes with the sims index (which consists of all rows from df_no. So the function is applied to each row in df_yes and, for each row, find the maximum similarity value and index(ices) of df_no.

With the toy data, it is fast, but with my real data, it is much too slow using `apply`. Here is the code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import gensim
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')

d = {'number': [1,2,3,4,5], 'text': ['do you like python', 'do you hate python','do you like apples','who is nelson mandela','i am not interested'], 'answer':['no','yes','no','no','yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_yes = df[df['answer']=='yes']

df_no = df[df['answer']=='no']
df_no = df_no.reset_index()

docs = df_no['text'].tolist()
genDocs = [[w.lower() for w in word_tokenize(text)] for text in docs]
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(genDocs)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(genDoc) for genDoc in genDocs]
tfidf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)
sims = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus], num_features=len(dictionary))

def get_search_results(row):
    tokenized_row = word_tokenize(row)
    query_bag_of_words = dictionary.doc2bow(tokenized_row)
    query_tfidf = tfidf[query_bag_of_words]
    search_result = sims[query_tfidf]
    max_similarity = max(search_result)
    index = [i for i, j in enumerate(search_result) if j == max_similarity]
    return max_similarity, index

df_yes = df_yes.copy()

df_yes['max_similarity'], df_yes['index'] = zip(*df_yes['text'].apply(get_search_results))
```

I have tried converting the operations to dask dataframes to no avail, as well as python multiprocessing. How would I make these functions more efficient? Is it possible to vectorize some/all of the functions?